# I am trying to use javascript to double the size of one image

Tags: javascript, html

My html do contains 3  images all the same size. I am trying to write some javascript so the third image the Jamaican flag I want to double went I move the mouse over it. I thought this code I wrote would work but it does not

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Task 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="usa.gif" height="200" width="250"/>
<img src="mexico.gif" height="200" width="250"/>
<img id = "jamaica"height="200" width="250"onMouseover = "setNewImage()" onMouseout = 
"returnOldImage()" src="jamaica.gif"/>

<script>
    var myImages = [
        "usa.gif",
        "canada.gif",
        "jamaica.gif",

    ];

    function setNewImage()
    {
        document.getElementById("jamaica").src="jamaica.gif" height="400" 
 width="500";
    }
    function returnOldImage()
    {
      document.getElementById("jamaica").src="jamaica.gif" height="200" width="250";
    }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is always greatly appreciated Thanks

Comment: you need to specify which element is having width and height changing... just `height = '400'` doesn't tell anything. capture the image in a variable: `let img = document.getElementById("jamaica")`  then use `img.height`

Comment: so in my function I would writevar myImages = [
            "usa.gif",
            "canada.gif",
            "jamaica.gif",

        ];

        function setNewImage()
        {
          let image =  document.getElementById("jamaica").src="jamaica.gif" img.height="400" img.width="500";
        }
        function returnOldImage()
        {
        let image =  document.getElementById("jamaica").src="jamaica.gif" height="200" width="250";
        }

Comment: no, you don't use the `.src` property in the end, you first select the element, then you modify its properties. 
`let img = document.getElementById("jamaica");` then `img.src = '...'; img.height = '...'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use CSS to transform the image on hover.  In the code snippet I've added a class to the `li` where the jamaica flag is enlarged on hover.  If you want any flag to enlarge on hover, just remove the `jamaica` class, and change the css from `ul li.jamaica a:hover img` to just `ul li a:hover img`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Transform with CSS</title>
<style>
    ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 50px 20px;
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul li {
        margin: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    ul li a {
        padding: 5px;
        display: inline-block;      
        border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    }
    ul li a img {
        width: 125px;
        height: 125px;
        display: block;
    }
    ul li.jamaica a:hover img {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/united-states-of-america/flag-square-250.png" alt="United States"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/canada/flag-square-250.png" alt="Canada"></a></li>
        <li class="jamaica"><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/jamaica/flag-square-250.png" alt="Jamaica"></a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**If you have to use JavaScript instead of CSS do this:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Task 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/united-states-of-america/flag-square-250.png" height="200" width="250"/>
<img src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/canada/flag-square-250.png" height="200" width="250"/>
<img src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/jamaica/flag-square-250.png" id="jamaica" height="200" width="250" onMouseover="setNewImage()" onMouseout ="returnOldImage()"/>

<script>
    var myImages = [
        "usa.gif",
        "canada.gif",
        "jamaica.gif",

    ];

    function setNewImage()
    {
        var jamImg = document.getElementById("jamaica");
        jamImg.style.height="400px";
        jamImg.style.width="500px";
    }
    function returnOldImage()
    {
        var jamImg = document.getElementById("jamaica");
        jamImg.style.height="200px";
        jamImg.style.width="250px";
    }

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I am doing this for a javascript class so I have to do it using script and not the css. but appreciate the input

Comment: @Mike I've added an example with just JavaScript.  Mark answer as accepted if it's what you're looking for :)